# how to use clickabe link (href link) in php mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

i want to use click able link in email, but it is not reflecting in email sending through php mail function, below is my code

```
$url = "<html><a href='www.google.com'>Link</a></html>";

$message = "Hi test url ".$url." ";

$$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Admin <test@ex.com> \r\n";
@mail('test1@ex.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Content which i'm getting from email:

```
Hi test url <html><a href='www.google.com'>Link</a></html> ##NEW##
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be sending HTML mail correctly. Usually I will recommend using a third-party PHP library, like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), to simplify the process.

Edit: If you still wish to use php's mail() function, you will have to specify the headers correctly. [This article](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) could help.

Answer (score 1):

To use the HTML in phpmailler:

```
$mail->isHTML(true)
```

You review the documantation

[phpMailler](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)